# Should I serialize .net objects to *file* using SOAPFormatter or XMLFormatter if the files are going to later be used by Unix+PC

Tags: c#, .net, unix, soap, xml-serialization

I have a desktop app that saves out user data (mostly arrays of numbers) to a file by Serializing an object. This file will later be used to reload user data by Deserialising it.

I would also like these files to be user-readable and in some standard structured format. The files will be manually moved around (not transmitted) and will be read by users on both PCs and Unix machines . Just to clarify - my desktop app will not run in Unix but I'd like the Unix users to be able to write a script to parse the data if they needed.

Is there a good reason to use the Soap formatter rather than XML formatter to do this?

Comment: Do you like one of these answers? You should mark one of them as your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the rule you were taut in Grad schools. When it comes to Platform Independence go with XML

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SOAP Formatter. The XML generated is quite bizarre and pretty unusable - I personally believe it is just a binary serialization but in SOAP.

Use `XmlSerializer` instead.